# What's the upload size limit for rpubs?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When uploading an rmarkdown file to Rpubs, I get an error below.

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with memory size, so my question is what is the size limit?

Answer (score 0):

does not look like a file size issue right now. unless you are uploading videos or high resolution photos, you should be okay. have you tried uploading this file from another computer. Maybe you can post a reprex and I can see if I get similar errors

Comment: Im loading a workspace with a lot of models at the beginning. Its worked until now. Heres the site example, https://rpubs.com/joshualerickson/streamoccurrence, ive added a lot of models.